# IBM Mobilefirst database design

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Need to IBM mobilefirst database using the server side scripting in the database design.To get datas from one place to the another place.

Answer (score 0):

If you are actually asking for the structure of the MobileFirst databases, you can find them here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/admin/r_internal_ibm_worklight_database_tables.html

This question does not fit Stack Overflow.